# Eclipse will not run, seems like Java issue

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runtime

I go to open Eclipse and it will not run, here is what it gives me, I could not copy and paste it:

If it helps, I tried running a .jar that I just made on it, but it did not open and did not give any error message

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://imgur.com/iIlq1Wv    Wouldn't put the picture up for some reason.

Comment: You are using a 64 bit Eclipse and almost certainly a 32 bit Java - they must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.